# How to find the length of one segment in a triangle when it is crossed by another triangle?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

> The figure from below shows a parallelogram $ABCD$ and
> $\triangle\,APD$ and $QR=3\,cm\,RD=4\,cm$. Using this information find
> the value of PQ.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\frac{3}{4}\,cm\\
2.&\frac{7}{3}\,cm\\
3.&\frac{10}{3}\,cm\\
4.&\frac{7}{10}\,cm\\
\end{array}$

So far the only relationship which I was able to spot was that since there's a parallelogram involved this meant.

$\angle BCA = \angle DAC.$

But that's where I'm still stuck. Is there any other relationship which can be obtained from what is given?.

Does this problem require construction or similarity or something like that?.

**Please include some drawing in the answer**. How, exactly, relying only in Euclidean geometry postulates can this be solved?.

Answer (score 1):

Triangles $\triangle QRC$ and $\triangle DRA$ are similar to each other by A.A.A

$$\frac{QC}{AD}=\frac{QR}{RD}=\frac{3}{4}$$

Hence

$$\frac{BQ}{AD}=\frac{1}{4}$$

And triangles $\triangle PBQ$ and $\triangle PAD$ are similar to each other by A.A.A

$$\frac{PQ}{PD}=\frac{PQ}{PQ+7}=\frac{BQ}{AD}=\frac{1}{4}$$

$$4PQ=7+PQ$$

$$PQ=\frac{7}{3}$$

Comment: Howdy, interesting solution, but it would had been nicer (as the OP of this question) if you could have **added** a drawing or perhaps reusing mine to explain over the figure the places were are the similarity. As I mentioned in the question, for me to read just plain equations is not very helpful in euclidean geometry explanations.

Comment: **Please** explain **why** $\frac{BQ}{AD}=\frac{1}{4}$ I see it many times and I just can't find a reason or a way to explain why or how did you come to that conclusion?.I'm assuming that this is due it mentions that the figure is a paralellogram and $AD=BC$ is this the reason why?. Can you better explain this part?.

Comment: @Chris Steinbeck Bell: $AD=BC$(Opposite sides of parallelogram are equal).  Since $\frac{QC}{AD}=\frac{3}{4}$,  let $AD=4a$ then $QC=3a$ and $BQ=AD-QC=4a-3a=a$. Finally $\frac{BQ}{AD}=\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: @Chris Steinbeck Bell: $\triangle QRC\sim \triangle DRA $(AAA Similarity Theorem).Since $\angle CQR= \angle ADR$ and $\angle QCR= \angle DAR$ (alternate interior angles,  $AD\parallel BC$).$\angle QRC=\angle ARD $(vertically opposite angles)

Comment: @Chris Steinbeck Bell: $\triangle PBQ\sim \triangle PAD $(AAA Similarity Theorem).Since $\angle PBQ= \angle PAD$ and $\angle PQB= \angle PDA$ (corresponding angles,  $AD\parallel BC$).$\angle BPQ=\angle APD $(common angle)